# Condition in Arden's rule

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

According to [Arden's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden%27s_rule), the language equation $X= AX\cup B$, with unknown $X$, has the solution $X=A^*B$, provided $A$ does not contain the empty string.

My question: what is the problem with the empty string here? Can you illustrate this with a concrete example (which lacks in Wikipedia on this topic).

Comment: See also [Why P cannot have NULL string in Arden's Theorem?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/111384/4287)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, for instance, $A = \{ \varepsilon \}$. Then $X = AX$, so $X = AX \cup B$ holds for any $X$ with $B \subseteq X$.